# Anime about two girls who have compact mirror-like things with little Tamagotchi-like creatures, and transform into cute outfits to battle monsters

Tags: story-identification, anime

So I think this show was from the 2000s:
It was an anime about two girls around high school age, one with black hair and the other a redhead. They both had these little compact mirror-looking things with little Tamagotchi-like creatures, and would transform into cute little fighting outfits to battle monsters.

The girl with black hair had a white and blue outfit, and the redhead had a black and pink one. Both had knee high boots and skirts, and their fighting outfits had cute little bows and whatnot on them. Anyone know what I'm talking about? Been looking for the name of this show for years now but I can never find it.

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like ***[Pretty Cure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futari_wa_Pretty_Cure)*** (2004-2005).

> *Futari wa Pretty Cure* (ふたりはプリキュア, *Futari wa PuriKyua*, lit. "We Are Pretty Cure"), known as simply *Pretty Cure* outside Japan, is a Japanese magical girl anime series produced by Toei Animation and broadcast across Japan on TV Asahi's ANN network. It is the first series in the *Pretty Cure* metaseries created by Izumi Todo. The original series, directed by Daisuke Nishio, aired on TV Asahi between February 1, 2004, and January 30, 2005, in the same timeslot as Izumi Todo's previous work Ashita no Nadja. It was the first of the *Pretty Cure* series to have received an adapted English-language version, which aired in United States From February 2005 And Also Canada from March 2009.

> Futari wa Pretty Cure revolves around two girls, Nagisa Misumi and Honoka Yukishiro, who encounter the Garden of Light's Mipple and Mepple, who give them the power to transform into the emissaries of light; Cure Black and Cure White, to fight against the forces of the Dark Zone: a dimension of evil that has encroached on the Garden of Light and is now about to do the same to the Garden of Rainbows, Earth. The Cures search for the Prism Stones, placing them in a heart-shaped device known as the Prism Hopish, protected by the Guardian, Wisdom. Once they have discovered all the Prism Stones, its power takes them to the Garden of Light and repairs most of the damage done by the Dark Zone. Later in the series, Porun, the Prince of the Garden of Light, grants the Pretty Cure duo use of their Rainbow Bracelets as they defeat the Dark King.

The two main characters certainly match your description, and they do each have a clamshell device, containing small Tamagotchi-esque creatures.

[image]

Comment: @Annie - If anyone correctly identifies the anime you're looking for, please mark that answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons. Or if the only answers posted are incorrect, please indicate that with a comment so we know to keep looking. Thanks.